# SegWit and previous hash: txid or wtxid, or either?

Tags: segregated-witness, transaction-id, transaction-input

With segwit there will be two transaction ids `wtxid` and `txid`
Can either one of them be used as previous hash or only txid?

Answer (score 6):

Inside transaction inputs, you have to refer to previous transactions using the txid. Allowing a wtxid there would be (1) a hard fork and (2) defeating the purpose, as it'd make transactions malleable again.

The wtxid is *only* used to compute the Witness merkle root, which is committed to in the coinbase.